# filter special characters in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, special-characters

I have the following dataframe called `data`:

```
    metrics    artists

0    0.21    ['ZhanÃ©']
2    0.14    ['Mose Allison']
3    0.87    ['水柳仙']
4    0.25    ['Shel Silverstein']
```

Some records of the column "artists" have special characters, I want to make another df with the records that have special characters, that is, the following output:

data:

```
     metrics    artists

0    0.14    ['Mose Allison']
1    0.25    ['Shel Silverstein']
```

data2:

```
     metrics    artists

0    0.21    ['ZhanÃ©']
1    0.14    ['水柳仙']
```

use:

```
 data2=data.artists[data.artists.str.contains("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")]
```

but I get the original df,

I also tried with:

```
data2 = []
for x in data['artists']:
    if x is not "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]":
         data2[x]=data[x]
    print(data2)
```

but it gives me the error:

```
KeyError: "['ZhanÃ©']"
```

and with:

```
if x is "[^ a-zA-Z0-9]"
```

returns empty records.

Comment: Actually your current approach with `str.contains` should be working.

Comment: Please provide the input dataframe. See [mre] for reference. You can [edit] the question. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: aren't you supposed to use re module for regex?

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas, so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use:
>
> data2=data.artists[data.artists.str.contains("[^a-zA-Z0-9]")]
>
> but I get the original df,

You're missing a space in "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" which is why you're getting the original df. Tested with Python3 in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: when validating if they enter the filter I get "True" in the registers, that's why it throws me all the original df

Comment: `data2 = data [data.artists.str.contains ("[^ a-zA-Z0-9]")]`

This worked for me. Maybe reply with what output you're getting using this?

Comment: I already tried it with another example and if it works, my problem I think is that my data comes as "['Shel Silverstein']" and not as "Shel Silverstein", I suppose that I will have to modify the format of the records first